# Is the time leakage by comparing the hashes of two strings vulnerable?

Tags: security, hash, comparison, timing-attack

It is obvious that if we compare two strings it is vulnerable to the time attack.

I'm now wondering whether the time leakage is still a vulnerability if the comparison is done on the hash of those two strings?

Isn't it vulnerable to any other kind of attacks? (Suppose using a hash algorithm which is safe against the collision attack).

Or simply what will happen if someone could find out the hash of the original string? Can it be abused?

Here is just an example of the idea:

```
user_pass = get_password_from_input();
if (memcmp(sha256(user_pass), sha256(HARD_CODED_PASS), SHA256_SIZE))
    printf("Welcome!");
else
    printf("Wrong Password!");
```

Comment: Yes because the hashes are also strings or byte arrays. Timing attacks can be prevented by using constant-time algorithms.

Comment: Sure, but how can the system be exploited if someone could find out the hash value? How can he/she create the original string?
BTW, I added this info into the question

Comment: They may be able retrieve the original value with a brute-force or dictionary attack. While timing attacks are not very practical, most decent libraries use constant time algorithms when comparing hashes/MACs, in order to prevent them.